# How to build a histogram from values of Counter?

Tags: python, histogram, counter

I used Counter() to count the number of occurrences of keys.

So I have `({'A':1, 'B':3, 'C':1, 'D':2, 'E':1, 'F':3, G:'2'})`

How can I use that information to build a histogram for the numbers of values:

- For 1 the value is 3
- For 2 the value is 2
- For 3 the value is 2

Comment: what's your data?

Comment: you want a histogram plot.?

Comment: My data is list of letters, and the histogram presents the distribution of quantities of letters.

Comment: Yes, I want a histogram plot.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a dictionary, so I guess you can use `bar` from `matplotlib`:

```
frequency_calculated = ({'A':1, 'B':3, 'C':1, 'D':2, 'E':1, 'F':3, 'G':2})
plt.bar(frequency_calculated.keys(), frequency_calculated.values())
```

with **result**:

[image]

**EDIT**

From calculated frequency your data looks like `a`, and you can plot histogram of that:

```
a = ('A','B','B','B','C','D','D','E','F','F','F','G','G')
plt.hist(a)
```

**with result:**

[image]

To display histogram you don't need to calculate frequency. Histogram differs from a bar graph, in the sense that a bar graph relates two variables, but a histogram relates only one.

[Difference between bar and histogram](https://stattrek.com/statistics/charts/histogram.aspx)

Comment: `list(d)` is sufficient. And *never* (even in a example) shadow built-ins, use a different variable name, e.g. `d` or `dct`.

Comment: Thanks, but it is not my question. I want the distribution for the quantities of letters.

Comment: @jpp without `list()` worked for me in python 2.7, but not in python 3. Did check with 3.7 now, and it's working, don't know what happened and why. About variable name, it's just an example, why so serious?!

Comment: @DejanMarić, Because new Python learners copy examples. Then they post new questions complaining why `dict()` doesn't work for them in their code. Thousands reach SO each year because of this lax practice.

Comment: @Alon histogram is created from only one value, while bar from 2. Can you show your data and why you calculated frequency anyway?

Comment: @jpp ok, makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

do you want this? corrected your dictionary's last element, as I think you meant what I wrote.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.Series({'A':1, 'B':3, 'C':1, 'D':2, 'E':1, 'F':3, 'G':2})
data.value_counts()

1    3
3    2
2    2
dtype: int64
```